# Create a user who only has access to a database and can create other users in it (Microsoft SQL Server)

Tags: sql-server, authentication

Hello I'm having problems with database rights and user creation.
I have never used SQL Server before and apologise if I don't understand everything.
After a lot of research I can't figure this out.

This is what my database looks like

`master`
 `|`
 `|-- GroupDB1`
 `|      |-- dbo.TablePrivate`
 `|      |-- dbo.TableSecure`
 `|`
 `|-- GroupDB2`
       `|-- dbo.TablePrivate`
       `|-- dbo.TableSecure`

My objective is the following: **Create a user in the GroupDB1 database who can only access GroupDB1.**
This user must be able to **create other users but these users must only be able to view the GroupDB1 database.** 
I need three types of user permission, one allowing me to have all the rights on the Tables of GroupDB1, another which can only modify the TablePrivate table and the other being only able to see the TablePrivate table.

Comment: The easiest solution is to add the user to `db_owner`. That fulfills your requirements.

Comment: But the user will be able to do what he wants all over the server, which I absolutely want to avoid.

Comment: No. `db_owner` only gives you privileges in a database. Not a server.

Comment: Okay, sorry. But how will this user be able to create another user? Since SQL Server does not allow the creation of users outside of master?

Comment: I've never used it before, but you probably want database contained users: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/contained-database-users-making-your-database-portable?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I will read this thank you.

Comment: With regards to read only, read write etc. You can either use built in database roles (i.e. `db_datareader` is read only) or create custom roles